# Como puedo dividir el valor de 2 count y multiplicarlo x 100 en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT i.start as fecha, COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir, COUNT(start) as totalit FROM incidences i WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY i.start
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo dividir el valor de 2 count y multiplicarlo x 100 por cada fila, mostrandolo en otra columna como la de la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿cómo podría hacer eso? Espero haberme explicado bien. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar en mysql:

```
SELECT i.start as fecha, COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir, COUNT(start) as totalit,
COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start) * 100 as 'Porcentaje'
FROM incidences i WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY i.start
```

Simplemente añade un "campo" más al select, que será el resultado de dividir los counts de totalir/totalit y multiplicarlo por 100. Mysql acepta operar sobre los campos del select sin ningún problema, incluso podrás dejarlo con los decimales que quieras usando `round()`:

```
round(COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start) * 100, 2) as 'Porcentaje'
```

Comment: Me sale el error de que desconoce los alias y no puede realizar la operación.

Comment: Entonces sustituye los aliases por el count que representan de nuevo y ya está

Answer (score 2):

Puedes repetir los `COUNT`:

```
SELECT i.start as fecha, 
       COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir, 
       COUNT(start)                 as totalit,
       (COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start)) * 100 
                                    as porcentaje      
       
       FROM incidences i 
       WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
             AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
       GROUP BY i.start
```

O si te resulta más claro, materializar los datos en una subconsulta:

```
SELECT t.fecha,
       t.totalir,
       t.totalit,
       (t.totalir / t.totalit) * 100 as porcentaje
       FROM (SELECT i.start as fecha, 
                    COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir, 
                    COUNT(start)                 as totalit
                    FROM incidences i 
                    WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                          AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                    GROUP BY i.start
             ) t
```